# Long running (background) workers in CloudFoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

Recently I went through VMWare webinar dedicated to their open-source PaaS called CloudFoundry. Very impressive but I couldn't figure out one thing. Their "competitors" like Heroku and Azure support the concept of background async workers in addition to sync web services/apps. Is there an equivalent in CloudFoundry?

Answer (score 3):

Currently there is not official support for workers. However, you can run a worker class application, but you do need to bind the http port that CF assigns.

CF will adopt support for non-web apps sometime in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Foundry recently (May 2012) added support for background workers and "standalone" apps. From their blog:

- [Cloud Foundry Improves Support For Background Processing](http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2012/05/01/cloud-foundry-improves-support-for-background-processing/)
- [Running Resque Workers on Cloud Foundry](http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2012/05/03/running-resque-workers-on-cloud-foundry/)
- [Running Workers on Cloud Foundry with Spring](http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2012/05/09/running-workers-on-cloud-foundry-with-spring/)
- [Running Standalone Web Applications on Cloud Foundry](http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2012/05/11/running-standalone-web-applications-on-cloud-foundry/)